# When I publish my wcf service, why do I see duplicate web configs?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, publish

After I publish my wcf service the root folder contains a web config, a svc, and a bin folder. In the bin folder, there is another web config. What is the one in the bin folder affecting? is it safe to delete it? How can I stop it from being published there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the properties of the web.config and change `Copy to Output Directory` to `Do not copy`